# How to choose same colors for same categories from two different dataframes while plotting them with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two dataframes, I am using to plot `geom_area` and `geom_line`. The categories are common in both dataframes, except their numerical value.

Below are my sample dataframes:

```
#df_one, for geom_area()
   Timestamp      Topic           Value_A
  01/01/2019     News           10
  02/01/2019     Sports         11
  03/01/2019     Entertainment  12
   ...
  01/01/2020     Weather        5
  02/01/2020     News           6
  03/01/2020     Business       7
   ...
  01/01/2021     Sports         8
  02/01/2021     Business       4
  03/01/2021     News           9
   ...
  29/12/2021     Entertainment  12
  30/12/2021     News           13
  31/12/2021     Sports         14
```

And this is the second one

```
#df_two, for line plot
  Timestamp      Topic         Value_B
  01/01/2019     Weather       1.0
  02/01/2019     Business      1.1
  03/01/2019     News          1.2
   ...
  01/01/2020     Entertainment  5.0
  02/01/2020     Sports         6.5
  03/01/2020     Business       7.3
   ...
  01/01/2021     Sports         8.8
  02/01/2021     Business       4.2
  03/01/2021     Sports         9.2
   ...
  29/12/2021     Business       1.2
  30/12/2021     News           1.3
  31/12/2021     Weather        1.4
```

I am doing the following steps:

```
#convert date column into proper format
df_one$Timestamp <- as.Date(df_one$Timestamp)

#sort according to dates
df_one <- df_one[order(as.Date(df_one$Timestamp, format="%Y/%m/%d")),]


library(randomcoloR)
n <- 15
my_cols_one <- distinctColorPalette(n)

names(my_cols_one) = unique(df_one$Topic) #I will use this for both since Topics are common

list_one <- 
  df_one %>%
  ## create year variable by which you split into a list
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(Timestamp)) %>%
  split(.$year) %>%
  ## pass this list to a loop function to create three separate plots 
  map(~ggplot(data = .x, aes(x=Timestamp, y=Frequency, fill=Topic)) + 
        scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = "%b-%y")+
        geom_area(alpha=0.6 , size=1, colour="black", position = position_fill())+
        theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box = "horizontal")+
        ggtitle("Reliable")+
        guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2, label.position = "bottom")) +
        scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = my_cols_one, limits = unique(.x$Topic))
  )

#now for df_two

#convert date column into proper format
df_two$Timestamp <- as.Date(df_two$Timestamp)

#sort according to dates
df_two <- df_two[order(as.Date(df_one$Timestamp, format="%Y/%m/%d")),]


df_two <- df_two %>% 
  group_by(created_at = lubridate::floor_date(created_at, "15 days"), Topic) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(Average_Value = mean(Value_B))


list_two <- 
  df_two %>%
  ## create year variable by which you split into a list
  mutate(year = lubridate::year(created_at)) %>%
  split(.$year) %>%
  ## pass this list to a loop function to create three separate plots 
  map(~ggplot(data = .x, aes(x=created_at, y=avg_sentiment, color=Topic)) + 
        scale_x_date(date_breaks = '1 month', date_labels = "%b-%y")+
        geom_line()+
        theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.box = "horizontal", plot.background = element_blank())+
        ggtitle("Title")+
        guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 2, label.position = "bottom")) +
        ## you will need to set the limits to the unique values in each plot
        ## I am also removing the guide title because of the visual crowding
        scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = my_cols_one, limits = unique(.x$Topic))+
        labs(title = '',
             x = 'Date',
             y = 'Average Value',
             color=""))
```

Now finally to plot these together

```
do.call("grid.arrange", c(list_one, list_two, ncol=2, nrow=2))
```

So the idea is to have two different plots of two years on top of each other using same color, to me, the output is different.

Any help please?

Comment: Where do you define `df_new`?

Comment: My apologies, its just df_two. I'll make the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

I was using `scale_fill_manual` for **df_two** whereas it should've been `scale_color_manual` since I was using `geom_line`.

So I changed `scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = my_cols_q, limits = unique(.x$Topic))`

to

`scale_color_manual(NULL, values = my_cols_q, limits = unique(.x$Topic))` and its working as expected.